# Adaptation to Banach–Mazur theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I'm trying to prove the following:

> For every normed linear space $X$, there exists a isometric ismorphism of $X$ in $C(K)$, where $K$ is a compact space.

I know from Banach–Mazur theorem that every separable Banach space satisfies the problem, so I tried to take a look at the demonstration of this theorem to have any idea how to solve this, but to prove that the function defined on the sketch of the proof of the theorem is in fact a isometry, we have to use Hahn-Banach, since the space $X$ is not necessary complete, I can't use this here and hence I'm stuck.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: There is an isometric embedding of $X$ into its completion $\hat{X}$, so in fact you can suppose $X$ complete.

Comment: The actual Banach-Mazur theorem shows something stronger: every separable normed space is isometric to a subspace of $C[0,1]$, not just $C(K)$ for *some* compact (metric) space.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the beginning the theorem should be read as follows:

> **Theorem** For every normed space $X$ there is isometric *embedding* into $C(K)$ for some compact space $K$.

**Proof.** Consider $K:=\operatorname{Ball}_X(0,1)$ with the weak-$^*$ topology. By the Banach-Alaoglu theorem it is compact. By definition of the weak-$^*$ topology the map 
$$
J(x): K\to\mathbb{C}:f\mapsto f(x)
$$
is continuous for each $x\in X$. So we have a well-defined map
$$
J:X\to C(K):x\mapsto J(x)
$$
Note that
$$
\Vert J(x)\Vert=\sup\{|J(x)(f)|:f\in K\}=\sup\{|f(x)|:f\in \operatorname{Ball}_X(0,1)\}=\Vert x\Vert
$$
for each $x\in X$. In the last step we use a corollary of the Hahn-Banach theorem. Thus $J$ is an isometric embedding.

Note that the corollary of the Hahn-Banach theorem does not require completeness, so its usage was valid in the proof above.